# Decoding base64 adds extra spaces

Tags: delphi, base64, decode, delphi-xe2

I am working in Delphi XE2
I am converting base64 byte array to string  using this

```
TEncoding.UTF7.GetString(byte1)
```

Then decoding string into byte array using this function

```
function Base64Decode(const EncodedText: string): TBytes;
var
  DecodedStm: TBytesStream;
  Decoder: TIdDecoderMIME;
begin
  Decoder := TIdDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
  try
    DecodedStm := TBytesStream.Create;
    try
      Decoder.DecodeBegin(DecodedStm);
      Decoder.Decode(EncodedText);
      Decoder.DecodeEnd;
      Result := DecodedStm.Bytes;
    finally
      DecodedStm.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Decoder.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But input string length is 400 and after decode its byte array length is 8192.

Somewhere it is adding extra spaces... any suggestion as what I'm doing wrong?

Edit...

this is base64 of my data send from c# through tcp to delphi XE2 app
string length = 400

```
TVpQAAIAAAAEAA8A//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAALoQAA4ftAnNIbgBTM0hkJBUaGlzIHByb2dyYW0gbXVzdCBiZSBydW4gdW5kZXIgV2luMzINCiQ3AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFBFAABMAQgAGV5CKgAAAAAAAAAA4ACOgQsBAhkArAoAAMQCAAAAAAAwugoA
```

i receive TBytes in my delphi app when i convert TBytes to string following comes

**Tbytes to UTF-7 string**
string length = 401

```
TVpQAAIAAAAEAA8A//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAALoQAA4ftAnNIbgBTM0hkJBUaGlzIHByb2dyYW0gbXVzdCBiZSBydW4gdW5kZXIgV2luMzINCiQ3AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA‘AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFBFAABMAQgAGV5CKgAAAAAAAAAA4ACOgQsBAhkArAoAAMQCAAAAAAAwugoA
```

TByte to UTF-8 String
string length= 0  ( ZERO)

TByte to ANSI String
string length= 401

```
TVpQAAIAAAAEAA8A//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAALoQAA4ftAnNIbgBTM0hkJBUaGlzIHByb2dyYW0gbXVzdCBiZSBydW4gdW5kZXIgV2luMzINCiQ3AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA‘AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFBFAABMAQgAGV5CKgAAAAAAAAAA4ACOgQsBAhkArAoAAMQCAAAAAAAwugoA
```

there is 1 extra bit is comming in between but i dont know why it is comming.

kindly advice am i doing any thing wrong.

Comment: You know that UTF-7 is not the same as Base64?

Comment: i have used ASCII, ANSI, Unicode, but same result. but in UTF-8 byte array length is 0. dont know why.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the result of TEncoding.UTF7.GetString is probably not a Base64 encoded string.

Comment: actually i am reading a binary exe file in c# and transfering the contents converting into base64string through udp to my delphi app. now i want to write the file on disk.

Comment: so the data is received in Tbytes. i am converting Tbytes into string using various encoding utf7, ASCII,ANSI. then decoding the string into Tbyte and then saving the file. but the file written is not in correct encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add one line to get the length you are expecting:

```
function Base64Decode(const EncodedText: string): TBytes;
var
  DecodedStm: TBytesStream;
  Decoder: TIdDecoderMIME;
begin
  Decoder := TIdDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
  try
    DecodedStm := TBytesStream.Create;
    try
      Decoder.DecodeBegin(DecodedStm);
      Decoder.Decode(EncodedText);
      Decoder.DecodeEnd;
      Result := DecodedStm.Bytes;
      SetLength(Result, DecodedStm.Size);  // add this line
    finally
      DecodedStm.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Decoder.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

While it is a very bad idea to mix UTF7 encoding with Base64 decoding, you should use the built-in functions `EncodeBase64` and `DecodeBase64` found in *Soap.EncdDecd.pas*.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, why are you involving UTF-7 at all?  Base64 is a 7-bit encoding that uses only ASCII characters.  Converting base64 to/from UTF-7 is an unnecessary operation.  If you have a `TBytes` that contains base64-encoded character octets, then you can simply copy the `TBytes` directly into an `AnsiString` without doing any decoding at all:

```
var
  byte1: TBytes;
  s: AnsiString;

SetString(s, PAnsiChar(byte1), Length(byte));
```

Or use Indy's `BytesToStringRaw()` function:

```
var
  byte1: TBytes;
  s: String;

s := BytesToStringRaw(byte1);
```

Either way, once you have a base64-encoded string, you can eliminate your custom `Base64Decode()` function completely by using the `TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeBytes()` method instead:

```
var
  decoded: TBytes;

decoded := TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeBytes(s);
```